# WooCommerce get_attributes is only returning the value for one attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to return the attribute values for my products in the order field. I've managed to return the array but it only returns the value of the first attribute.

```php
$att = $product->get_attributes();
print_r($att);
```

returns

```
Array ( [pa_logo-position] => centre [pa_colours] => )
```

It returns the correct value for pa_logo-position, but nothing for pa_colours, even though it does have a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was my mistake on the product set up. Even though I set the colours attribute to show as variations, the individual variations were not set up in the background. Once adding all the variations this now works.